Number of bits flips needed to reduce the rank of a binary matrix
Consider an $n$ by $n$ binary matrix. If it has rank $r \leq n$, then what is the largest number bits flips needed to reduce its rank? All computations should be done over $\mathbb{F}_2$ (that is $\bmod 2$).
If $r = n$, then the answer is $1$ I believe. If $r = 1$ the answer is $n^2$ by considering the all ones matrix.
For any given matrix with rank at least 1, there is a minimum number of bit flips needed to reduce its rank. I am looking for the maximum of these minima taken over all $n$ by $n$ binary matrices as a function of $n$ and the rank $r$.

Do you really want the largest number or the smallest? If you want the largest number then the matrix consisting of the cyclic shifts of the vector $(0,1,1,\ldots,1)$ for $n\equiv 0 (2)$ is invertible (so $r=n$) and thus the maximal number to reduce its rank is at least $n(n-1)$ (flipping all the 1's).

Let me try to clarify your question: If you have a matrix M of rank r, it may be that changing any one bit doesn't lower its rank; changing any two bits also doesn't. But if you change the right 3 bits, the rank drops. I'll call that count, 3, by the name $d(M)$. If your question (for a given $(r, n)$ pair),  "what is the maximum of $d(M)$, taken over all $n \times n$ matrices of rank $r$?"?

An alternative is that you take your matrix $M$ and see how many bits, $e(M)$, you can flip without altering its rank, perhaps choosing the order of the bit-flips very carefully. Now, for a given $(r,n)$ pair, the question is "What is the maximum of $e(M)+1$ over all n-by-n matrices of rank $r$?"  Both are plausible interpretations of "what is the largest number of bit flips needed to reduce its rank?"

Could anyone explain the close votes please?

If $r=n$ then the answer is $1$. Indeed, let $r_1,\dots,r_n$ be the rows of the matrix. Since they are linearly independent, they span the space of all binary vectors of the length $n$. Therefore there exist $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb F_2$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i r_i=(1,0,\dots,0)$. Then there exists a natural number $j\le n$ such that both $\lambda_j$ and the first entry of $r_j$ are $1$. When we flip this entry we obtain the new row $r_j$ and now $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i r_i=0$, so the rank of the new matrix is less than $n$.

@AlexRavsky. If $r = n - 1$ the answer appears to be 3 but I don't know why.

Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12586/can-this-matrix-problem-be-formulated-as-an-ilp-or-using-constraint-programming

Now I am trying to find the answer for $r=2$, but there are several cases to consider and it is not clear how to unite them.

Not a complete answer, more of an extended comment
I'm sure you've thought of this already, but your "all 1s" example generalizes somewhat in the "middle rank" case. Suppose that $n = 30$. Let
$v_1$ be a vector with the first ten bits "on" and the next 20 "off"; let $v_2$ have its 'middle' ten bits on, and $v_3$ have its last ten bits on.
Now let $M$ consist of 10 copies of $v_1$, then 10 copies of $v_2$, then ten copies of $v_3$, hence rank 3.  To reduce the rank, you're going to need to get rid of all the copies of one of those vectors, which means (if you change them all to the zero vector) altering $10 \cdot 10$ bits. That's still $O(n^2)$ bits. I guess it'd be better to say it's $O( (n/r)^2 )$. For large $n$, this same replication trick will still work, at least for small $r$. By the time you reach $r = n/2$, there's no longer much payoff to the "repeat some columns" approach.
BTW, in your "all 1s" example for rank 1, it's interesting that to reduce the rank, you actually have to increase it first.
Anyhow, just some random thoughts about the problem, too long for a comment.
